# Does someone encounter this kind of error while publishing in visual studio 2019? VB.NET language

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not copy "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.XmlSerialize.dll" to "bin\Debug\app.publish\Application Files\Tito Tea POS and Inventory_1_0_0_0\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.XmlSerialize.dll.deploy". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.    Tito Tea POS and Inventory

I already tried copying the dll files from SAP Crystal Report folder to my app.publish but it says it can't delete it if I paste it there.

Comment: Don't post pictures of error messages. They are text so post them as text, formatted appropriately. You should have taken the site tour when prompted in order to learn more about how to use this site properly.

Comment: I'm sorry it's just I need help. I'll edit it